# How to import a private key to an encrypted wallet (on standard client)

Tags: wallet, backup, encryption, wallet-recovery

I have a standard client (QT client on OSX) with an encrypted wallet. I've tried to import keys with pywallet, but while it claimed to be importing them, when I ran again the bitcoin client, it said wallet.dat was corrupted (yes the client wasn't running when I did the import).

I guess pywallet doesn't know about encryption and didn't care enough to check everything was ok before importing them.

So, how do I do this import?

---

Trying to run the command line client gets me the following error a few seconds after starting it (with -daemon option of course):

```
EXCEPTION: NSt8ios_base7failureE       
CDataStream::read() : end of data       
bitcoin in AppInit()
```

---

Running the QT client with the `-server` option crashes too after a while (apparently it works correctly without that).

Comment: I managed to import them to MultiBit, however it isn't working anyway: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3549/why-does-multibit-claim-my-balance-is-zero-btc

Answer (score 5):

Since 0.6.0, key import/export are available in the client itself, though only through RPC. The commands are called `dumpprivkey` and `importprivkey`. For example (on testnet):

> $ ./bitcoind getnewaddress
>
> n2JjZgLeCUgfubswxDm9zAaBGSLLHSLdNv
>
> $ ./bitcoind dumpprivkey n2JjZgLeCUgfubswxDm9zAaBGSLLHSLdNv
>
> cR4RtpaeAZY8MwrNvTQGX9PZ9pdCgFoLxuo4Pkwqx61broC4Gb4y

And on another wallet:

> $ ./bitcoind importprivkey R4RtpaeAZY8MwrNvTQGX9PZ9pdCgFoLxuo4Pkwqx61broC4Gb4y
>
> $ ./bitcoind validateaddress n2JjZgLeCUgfubswxDm9zAaBGSLLHSLdNv
>
> {
>       "isvalid" : true,
>       "address" : "n2JjZgLeCUgfubswxDm9zAaBGSLLHSLdNv",
>       "ismine" : true,
>       "pubkey" : "029e3a934cfc9f89d7a1c15f99b98479cabc81964f4972e7b8fa3989a788261695",
>       "iscompressed" : true,
>       "account" : ""
>   }

Comment: Oh, apparently bitcoin-qt doesn't provide a server for the command line client to connect to; also looks like bitcoind isn't starting anymore, crashing with an exception a few seconds after it started... (does it support encrypted wallets? in the options I noticed nothing about that...)

Comment: You need to run "bitcoin-qt -server" to get it to provide a server.  And you'll need to have 'rpcuser=x' and 'rpcpassword=y' in your bitcoin.conf file, but I think bitcoin-qt will tell you that if you don't have it.  bitcoind supports encrypted wallets, but make sure you're using the same version as the version of bitcoin-qt you have.

Comment: @ChrisMoore mmmh, doing so I only get errors -4"Error adding key to wallet" if I try to add `priv_sipa` or -5"Invalid private key" if I try to add `priv`

Comment: Oh, you need to unencrypt your wallet temporarily so it can add the new key.  I do the following, so my passphrase doesn't end up in my shell history.  It unlocks the wallet for 60 seconds: read x; ./bitcoind walletpassphrase "$x" 60; unset x

Comment: I can't do that: if I run the server from command line, it crashes after a while, and the same happens if I run the QT client with the -server option.

Comment: Then that's a bug. Can you report it on github? Nonetheless, this answer is how importing of keys is intended to be done.